# Gradle couldn't locate the Spring core jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

i am spring boot using gradle build. till yesterday gradle build was run smoothly. But today i got this following error ;

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find spring-core.jar (org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:20190328.215418-203).
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-20190327.205120-195.jar
>   Could not find spring-jcl.jar (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:20190328.215418-203).
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-jcl-5.2.0.BUILD-20190327.205120-195.jar

this is my `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven {url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'idea'

group = 'me.namila'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

When visiting the relevant url,what i can see is gradle is searching for 27th march build (`spring-jcl-5.2.0.BUILD-20190327.205120-195.jar`) while the server has the 28th build `spring-jcl-5.2.0.BUILD-20190328.164750-201.jar`. how to fix this error? i have added buildscript repositories too. any suggesions?

Comment: Maybe snapshot build is broken :)

Comment: @Antoniossssso how to fix it :/ i need to run the project

Comment: Use earlier build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Antoniossss said in the comments, this happened because snapshot build failure. To fix it i moved to previous build version of springboot. i did the following changes to the `build.gradle` file;

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
```

changed the `'2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'` to 2.1.3 release. this fixed the error. :)

Answer (score 0):

the `buildscript` repositories & dependencies are a mess, there's a mismatch:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

see the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/gradle-plugin/reference/html/).